# ReactJS with CKEditor 5 / CKFinder CORS issue when developing

Tags: reactjs, cors, ckfinder, ckeditor5

If I build my ReactJS project and put the build on my Apache server everything works fine. I can successfully upload images with CKEditor 5.

The problem is that while developing the port used to render the ReactJS page is 3000 (http://localhost:3000) so the CKFinder won't work because of the security limitations (the CKFinder is on http://localhost:80).

Is there any workaround to make it work? I need to do build some custom functions to handle pictures, so it would be a great help to be able to view the result without having to build every time the project.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use some reverve tool such as nginx:

1. change your upload api to normal 3000 port
2. proxy the upload api to 80 port
   it working now

Answer (score 0):

You can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header to all CKFinder connector responses. See [`headers`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_headers) option.

Comment: I already tried that, but as soon as I add the code to config.php even the version residing on the same server/port stops working. It says "Cannot upload file: IMG-0361.JPG" no errors in the console.

Comment: @devamat Try disabling CSRF prtection: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/configuration.html#configuration_options_csrfProtection

`$config['csrfProtection'] = false;`